# KeyError when applying with multiple conditions including the date format to Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I am trying to automate this script but I am running with some issues regarding the date column.

Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv("Vulns_110421.csv")
df['Vulnerable Since'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Vulnerable Since'], format='%Y/%m/%d')
critical = pd.to_datetime('2021-10-2')
severe = pd.to_datetime('2021-9-2')
moderate = pd.to_datetime('2021-8-02')

conditions = [
    (df['Vulnerability CVSSv3 Score'] >= 7.5) & (df['Vulnerable Since'] <= critical),
    (df['Vulnerability CVSSv3 Score'] >= 7.5) & (df['Vulnerability Since'] > critical),
    (df['Vulnerability CVSSv3 Score'] >= 3.5) & (df['Vulnerability CVSSv3 Score'] < 7.5) & (df['Vulnerability Since'] <= severe),
    (df['Vulnerability CVSSv3 Score'] >= 3.5) & (df['Vulnerability CVSSv3 Score'] < 7.5) & (df['Vulnerability Since'] > severe),
    (df['Vulnerability CVSSv3 Score'] >= 0) & (df['Vulnerability CVSSv3 Score'] < 3.5) & (df['Vulnerability Since'] <= moderate),
    (df['Vulnerability CVSSv3 Score'] >= 0) & (df['Vulnerability CVSSv3 Score'] < 3.5) & (df['Vulnerability Since'] > moderate)
]
values = ['Critical', 'Critical_Past_Due', 'Severe', 'Severe_Past_Due', 'Moderate', 'Moderate_Past_Due']
df['Kratos_Vuln_Severity'] = np.select(conditions, values)

df.to_excel("Vulns_110421-B.xlsx")
```

---

Below is the error I am getting.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\****\Documents\GitHub\python\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 3361, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 76, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 108, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 5198, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 5206, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: 'Vulnerability Since'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\****\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\PyCharmCE2021.2\scratches\scratch_5.py", line 12, in <module>
    (df['Vulnerability CVSSv3 Score'] >= 7.5) & (df['Vulnerability Since'] > critical),
  File "C:\Users\****\Documents\GitHub\python\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 3458, in __getitem__
    indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
  File "C:\Users\****\Documents\GitHub\python\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 3363, in get_loc
    raise KeyError(key) from err
KeyError: 'Vulnerability Since'
```

Comment: You do not have a column named `Vulnerability Since`. As simple as that.

Comment: You don't appear to have a `'Vulnerability Since'` column in the DataFrame (condition 2 (index 1)). Should that be `'Vulnerable Since'`?

Comment: Thank you! that solves my issue.

Comment: I got my script working. Thanks to Henry. Is there any efficient way to do this? I am learning python and I want to explore and expand my knowledge.